# How can I change the ActionBar color of individual fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

Is there any way to change the ActionBar color of fragments and change the title displayed in the ActionBar to the title of the menu option that was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

This is the suggested answer written in java :

```
  getActionBar().setTitle("Test");
  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

Comment: I was able to change the title with getActivity().setTitle("Test"); however when I implement the color using yours or @Muhammad's code, the app crashes when opening the fragment I changed the color of.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using AppCompat you always have to call getSupportActionBar()

Change Title : 
`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");`

Change Color :
`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YOUR_COLOR));`

> If in Fragment :

Change Title :
`getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("YOUR TITLE");`

Change Color : 
`getActivity().getAcationBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YOUR_COLOR));`

Hope this help you

Comment: I was able to change the title with getActivity().setTitle("Test"); however when I implement the color, the app crashes when opening the fragment I changed the color of.

Comment: using ```getActionBar()``` after ```getActivity()```

Comment: yup, I tried that. The code uploads fine, and I can open my app to its home screen, but when I click the menu icon that brings me to the fragment with the changed color action bar, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using support libraries:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

if (supportActionBar  != null) {
    supportActionBar.setTitle("My action bar title");
    View view = new View(getContext());
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)); 
    supportActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getBackground());
}
```

Otherwise:

```
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setTitle("My action bar title");
    View view = new View(getContext());
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));         
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getBackground());
}
```